# Unable to open text file from WebBrowser control

Tags: javascript, vb.net, webbrowser-control, text-files

I have a sample application, in which I am trying to load a text file in WebBrowser control. I have a html file through which I am calling Javascript function to open text file. But it is showing me error like;

Cannot find 'file:///C:/temp/test%2520page.txt'. Make sure the path or Internet address is correct.

File exist at this location and its name is; test page.txt.

I am not getting what is happening. Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the Javascript function that opens the file look like? Where does the address to the file ("file:///C:/temp/test%2520page.txt") come from? It seems like it's improperly URL-encoded.

Comment: Post this "Javascript function".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to open the wrong fil. %25 translates to the '%' character. So it looks like you are trying to escape the % of %20 somehow. The file you want to open is 'file:///C:/temp/test%20page.txt'